# assigning a variable to each row for a excel format on R

Tags: r

So i have a excel file with 5 columns and 100 rows. I import this to R.

I want to make unique list vector for each of the rows. Each vector would then contain 5 elements.

My issue is how do i make R to automatically assigns 100 unique variable names and assign each row elements to those variables? I don't want to manually assign variable names to each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `split` function for that. An example:

```
# creating a data.frame
df <- data.frame(x=gl(2,10, labels=c("t","c")), y=runif(20))
# splitting the dataframe df in seperate dataframes
lst <- split(df, 1:nrow(df))
```

This will create a list of dataframes `lst`. You can access the separate dataframes as follows:

```
> lst[1]
$`1`
  x        y
1 t 0.971842
```

---

A slightly alternative approach:

```
# creating a data.frame
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(20), y=runif(20))
# creating a unique value for each row
df$unique <- paste0("u",seq_len(20))
# splitting the dataframe df in seperate dataframes
lst <- split(df, df$unique)
```

this gives for example:

```
> lst$u11
          x         y unique
11 1.511781 0.4776196    u11
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!